# is it possible to login to gmail in a normal way, but firing submit button programatically?

Tags: gmail

I have User name and password, or gmail.
My goal is to make a link or a button on which user clicks and user can see his gmail inbox page in separate tab. Like a normal user does.
i just want to skip login page to be shown.

Comment: Yes it it! Just tell us what you tried and you might even get some feedback :)

Comment: language? platform? browser plugin? executable application? a script? website? What have you tried before?

Comment: Using Javascript, any standard browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a local copy of the form / login page that submits the login to gmail and fill them out with teh credentials you want.  Once the page is loaded you auto submit the form in the page.

When you open the local copy, it will basically bypass the login on gmail.

Comment: So thats the only solution we can have.